# What exactly 0 && checksum != stored_checksum do?

Tags: sshd

http://www.vegardno.net/2017/03/fuzzing-openssh-daemon-using-afl.html

```
diff --git a/packet.c b/packet.c
--- a/packet.c
+++ b/packet.c
@@ -1635,7 +1635,7 @@ ssh_packet_read_poll1(struct ssh *ssh, u_char *typep)

        cp = sshbuf_ptr(state->incoming_packet) + len - 4;
        stored_checksum = PEEK_U32(cp);
-       if (checksum != stored_checksum) {
+       if (0 && checksum != stored_checksum) {
                error("Corrupted check bytes on input");
                if ((r = sshpkt_disconnect(ssh, "connection corrupted")) != 0 ||
                    (r = ssh_packet_write_wait(ssh)) != 0)
```

Can someone please explain what does this patch do?:

It removes this:

```
-       if (checksum != stored_checksum) {
```

and adds this:

```
+       if (0 && checksum != stored_checksum) {
```

What exactly `0 && checksum != stored_checksum` do?

Comment: If you read the line above the listing of this code in your reference.. it bypasses the test logic by always being false.. the text above states "The first thing we can disable is the packet CRC test:". So the test to see if the checksums are different never get run, and the logic will continue as if it all checked out.